# Single page applications and <form> elements

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, single-page-application

Are there still any benefits of using a `<form>` element instead of let's say a `<div>` element in the context of a single page application? The purpose of the `<form>` element makes sense to me if the "form" submission isn't made with an ajax call (I'm talking about the more traditional way of submitting a form, with a input/button of type "submit" and the action attribute of the form element that describes the url to call), but otherwise I do not see it's utility (maybe for search engines?).

Comment: 1. form elements make clear your intentions. 2. some methods only work with forms like `serialize()`

Comment: For my information, is the "serialize" method you are talking about from PHP?

Comment: No, I meant from jquery. Sorry, should have made that clear

Comment: Ah, no problem! Surprisingly, I have never used or needed this method, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Semantically, using `<form>` is clearer than `<div>`.
2. If you still want your form to work **without** JavaScript, you'd better choose `<form>` (since you used the word *application*, this may not be considered though).
3. More importantly, it'll be really painful of using `<div>` if you do care about **accessibility**.

Comment: Perfect! If anyone has more arguments as to why the form element is better than a div for an actual form, in the context of a single page application, don't hesitate to comment below.

Comment: Accessibility shouldn't be optional. Using semantic HTML mark-up and relevant attributes achieve SEO and accessibility conformance with ease. When a framework malfunctions b/c of using correct markup, it's clear the makers didn't understand the nature of HTML to begin with and makes me wonder what other "gems" are in there waiting to mess up conformance and SEO.

Comment: Instead of a <button type="submit">Submit</button> use a <button type="button">Submit</button>. It'll work like a charm and you won't need any extra JS to re-enable submitting a form when you actually want to send data.

Comment: How would a single page app work *without* javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is, no, if you're not going to "submit" a form, there's no need for the <form tag.  Very often, our interactive controls are in places that would not be considered a "form" - checkboxes here, select menus there.  I think most of them work just fine without a

Accessibility, I don't know anything about.

Comment: Accessibility is automatically built-in based on semantic HTML mark-up and attributes. If you can't use the correct mark-up you're damaging your application's experience, seo, and accessibility conformance.